# Does visual studio require .net framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm new to .net framework. Have few queries.

1. Does visual studio requires .net framework to be pre installed in the system.
2. Does visual studio comes with .net framework within it. So no need to install separately.
3. If .net framework comes within visual studio, is it different version for different vs versions.
4. I have seen that in application tab we have target framework, may I know from where all these different versions of .net framework visual studio has.
5. Application developed with one version say 4.5 , can this run on 4.0 and do we have to modify this version first to 4.0 and then run it.

Comment: Try referring Visual Studio docs and googling, it will give you direct links to all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

When you're installing VS it's automatically install default version of .net framework for current Visual Studio , but you can additionally install any other versions if you need, it's like an additional nozzle to the vacuum cleaner :-)

Comment: Thank you. So that means I can install vs 2010 say and then later add higher versions of .net framework within it say 4.5,4.6 etc will that run?

Comment: yep, possibly not all functionality will be available and completely supported in VS2010, but why so old version?

Comment: The  .NET framework isnt only in the *download package* of VS already included. With installing Windows you already got a version of the .NET framework, since there is the CLR (Comman Language Runtime) included. Which is needed to execute any .exe file, which is programmed in a .NET language. Because in any *.exe or *.dll (created with .NET) isnt machine code, it's just IL (Intermediate Language) code. So once you execute your programm (the .exe file) the CLR uses its integrated jitter (Just-In-Time Complier) to compile the IL code into machine code.

Comment: So without the .NET framework installed you would not be able to exeute any programm that someone did programm in a .NET language. But creating not instant .exe files that contain machine code, you make your application more flexibel. Because it is not binded to a specific processor for instance, because it gets compiled just when you execute it, so you get your own machine code compiled version for your specific processor.